# Rendering both cycles and internal in one

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

My blender project has the mountain in cycles and the water in internal, how do i render both in one scene. But when i use render, i have to change the engine to see it.

Comment: I have done this before. I can't write a full answer now, but render your water in one scene and your mountains in another. Use transparent backgrounds and png format for each. Combine the two scenes with render layer nodes in the compositor.

Answer (score 1):

Open the .BLEND *Twice.*

Render each separately (Make sure transparency is enabled for the top layer)

Go to the Movie Sequence editor in one of the files (You can close the other)

Add in both rendered outputs and layer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can't render both(cycles and internal) in one type of engine.You can't also use cycle in blender game engine.

If you do it you will lost your materials/texture.

Even if you want you can bake cycles(mountain) and take that texture/material to internal.

How to bake:https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/baking.html